# Blazor 8 - The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

I execute this

```
dotnet new blazor  --interactivity auto -o xxx
```

then

```
dotnet run
```

and I get it up in the browser - np

Then I open the solution in Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.8.7

and try to run it but then I get

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   xxx C:\Projects\samples\xxx\xxx\Program.cs  1   Active

The namespace is used here

```
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(xxx.Client._Imports).Assembly);
```

Is this a new problem in VS ?

This is my project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xxx.Client\xxx.Client.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Followed your steps, guess what?  It worked, so there's something your not telling us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, even updated to what I thought was the latest version of Visual Studio, namely  *17.8.7* - **however** this is **not the latest version**.

Open the Visual Studio installer and install **version 17.9.2** and the problem is gone.

Even though I thought the problem was different, it's actually the same problem posted over-and-over again, a version mismatch between the .NET framework and Visual Studio.

Comment: I also did the upgrade and it works - thx